# Code returns JSON error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, syntax-error

This probably has been answered elsewhere but I for the life of me can not get this to work.

Here is my  html:

```
        <!Doctype html>
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="JS.js"></script>  
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and here is my Js file:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  console.log( 'ready!' );

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?appid=730&currency=3&market_hash_name=StatTrak%E2%84%A2%20M4A1-S%20|%20Hyper%20Beast%20(Minimal%20Wear)',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        var lowestprice = $( 'lowest_price' );
        console.log($target);
    }
});
});
```

The result of the query is:

```
{"success":true,"lowest_price":"48,--\u20ac","volume":"12","median_price":"51,02\u20ac"}
```

but I get the `error uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`

Thank you in advance, I'm experimenting with web programming and am struggling cause I am more used to object oriented programming.

Comment: which line is that error reported from. Your JSON looks fine and I cant see what (in the code you posted) might throw that error. That your code contains `console.log($target)` and `$target` is not defined anywhere makes me think you're not showing all the relevant parts

Comment: look at this link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43821423/web-method-return-ok-but-fire-fail-function/43821603#43821603

Comment: It usually tells you what line the problem is. the js looks fine

Comment: `var lowestprice = $( 'lowest_price' );` will not work until `.` (class selector) or `#`(id selector) not used with  `'lowest_price' `

Comment: That response ain't JSONP. You can not just use JSONP to get around CORS, the api needs to support it.

Comment: The error does not give me a line number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, its cross domain and the url should be modified to use HTTPS (i just tried it on w3school's editor. (otherwise, browser will block such url...)

Next, you need to use JSON instead of JSONP. After that, you will start getting status 200 ok. This is what i tried

```
   $.ajax({
        url: 'https://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?appid=730&currency=3&market_hash_name=StatTrak%E2%84%A2%20M4A1-S%20|%20Hyper%20Beast%20(Minimal%20Wear)',
        type: 'GET',
           dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
            var lowestprice = $( 'lowest_price' );
            console.log($target);
        },
           error: function(st, err) {
            alert('vijay');
            alert(st.status);
            alert(err);
           }
    });
```

Now, you have to add that cross-domain header...This page will tell you the explanation in detail.

https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Answer (score 1):

You are saying the endpoint is JSONP when you make the Ajax Request. The api returns JSON so when it is injected into the page it generates the error you see.

You can not just make any call JSONP by setting it in the Ajax call. The API needs to support JSONP.

Check the API to see if it supports JSONP. If it does set whatever querystring argument it requires. If it does not support it, than you would need to use a serverside proxy to make the call.

Comment: What api will support JSONP or how can I make this happen.

Comment: I do not know if that API supports it, you would need to read its documentation to see if it does.